# Stackdriver error reporting for GKE cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

I have a cluster on GKE.

Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring Enabled

In my errors list (https://console.cloud.google.com/errors/) I see errors with stack traced `Seen in gke_instances`.

But I don't get how to determine which particular container it relates to. Not sure why it doesn't "workout of the box".

And I don't get how to make it right, any advice?

Comment: Looks like this is not currently supported with Stackdriver. There is an ongoing [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/62828996) with Stackdriver Error reporting to associate logs from GKE containers with container name. You might need to visit there and comment your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: It would have been helpful for us to understand the issue if you could have posted the error message Instead of the project link.